# Binding Properties within a Class which is a Property within a ViewModel

Tags: mvvm, binding, maui

I have a `MainPageViewModel` coded as below which has Properties which are bound through a View.

For example:

```
private string _status;
public string Status
{
    get { return _status; }
    set
    {
        _status = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(Status));
    }
}
```

Full `MainPageViewModel.cs` at:

https://github.com/mainroads/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/blob/mvvm/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/MVVM/ViewModels/MainPageViewModel.cs

For example, they are bound as below in the View:

```
<Label x:Name="lblStatus" Text="{Binding Status}"></Label>
```

Full XAML at:

https://github.com/mainroads/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/blob/mvvm/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/MVVM/Views/MainPage.xaml

I was hoping to move these Properties to an `AppDataModel` class as below:

https://github.com/mainroads/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/blob/mvvm/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/MVVM/Models/AppDataModel.cs

I would then access all the properties through an `AppData` object:

```
private AppDataModel _appData = new AppDataModel();
public AppDataModel AppData
{
    get { return _appData; }
    set
    {
        _appData = value;
        OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AppData));
    }
}
```

That way, my plan was to bound the same Properties as below:

```
<Label x:Name="lblStatus" Text="{Binding AppData.Status}"></Label>
```

However, once I do this change, the Properties are not bound.

Is this a limitation in Net or am I missing something?

Thanks,

Michael

P.S:

I have tried to create the AppData Property the same way, but to no avail:

```
    // TODO: Try AppData
    /*
    private AppDataModel _appData = new AppDataModel();
    public AppDataModel AppData
    {
        get { return _appData; }
        set
        {
            _appData = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(nameof(AppData));
        }
    }
    */
```

`AppDataModel.cs` inherits the `ObservableModel.cs`:

https://github.com/mainroads/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/blob/mvvm/SpecifiedRecordsExporter/MVVM/Models/ObservableModel.cs

Comment: I suggest you edit your question so that the all the code is here, not on links. It becomes hard to follow

Comment: But only the relevant code parts or in other words a [minimal-reproducible-example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks, I believe I have added more code snippets to clarify my question.

Comment: What is the BindingContext of the page?

Comment: Hi Jason, the BindingConext of `MainPage` is `MainPageViewModel`.

I have got it here:
`
    <ContentPage.BindingContext>
        <local:MainPageViewModel />

    </ContentPage.BindingContext>
`
Is that adequate?

Comment: if `AppData` is a property on your VM there is no reason you can't bind to it or it's child properties.

Comment: Hi Jason, I am not sure why it did not work for me yesterday. I must have tried something differently. It works now!